# How can I save multiline text from a multiline textbox into database in ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am working on a web development project where I want add details for particular foods. So I added a multiline textbox where I want to type the details. I wanted to save that details into database and later wanted to use those text in another page reading from the database. But when I am showing those text into another webpage all the text are showing into single line. 
What should I do to resolve this problem?

Comment: Why are you using a multiline textbox?

Comment: @Vajura: Why do you care?

Comment: Carriage returns don't render on a web page.  When you display the text you need to replace carriage returns with "br" tags.

Comment: You can check this:- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4883613/asp-net-text-with-linebreak-from-multi-line-textbox-to-save-in-a-database

Comment: Thanks, i got the answer now. @Rahul

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try showing the \n (new line) this way:

```
text.Replace("\n","<br/>")
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **textarea** instead of **textbox** and then get data using `getInnerHTML`
this helps to save formatted data