# Display All Enteries On New Line From An asp:TextBox

Tags: html, css, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I have an `asp webform` site and on one page i have a `asp:TextBox` with `TextMode="MultiLine"` the field code is shown below

```
<asp:TextBox ID="Step04OtherField" runat="server" class="form-control" style="max-width: 100%" TextMode="MultiLine" Rows="5"></asp:TextBox>
```

this page stores all details on the page in a session and then displays the enteries on the next page.  The thing is even though the user may have entered 2 enteries in the textbox and each time clicked the enter key, it displays on one line on the confirmation page so isn't really that clear.

Is there a way to do this so that when the session value is displayed on the confirmation page, each enter key press also displays on a new line on this page

**Session store code behind**

```
Session["Step04OtherField"] = Step04OtherField.Text;
```

**Confirmation page HTML**

```
<div class="form-group">
    <asp:Label ID="Step04BrowsersLabel" class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 control-label" runat="server" Text="Browser(s) to check on:"></asp:Label>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-9 form-control-static">
         <%=Session["Step04OtherField"] %>
    </div>
</div>
```

When when the page is displayed it displays as:
**Browser(s) to check on**: Entry1 Entry2 etc

What i would like is for it to be displayed as something like

**Browser(s) to check on**: Entry1
                            
                                           Entry2
                            
                                           etc

Comment: I suspect this answer is probably what you need to do http://stackoverflow.com/a/4883627/1191903

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work for the text part:

```
    Session["Step04OtherField"] = Step04OtherField.Text.Replace("\r\n", "<br />");
```

Then for the html formatting:

```
    <table>
            <row>
                <td valign="top">Browser(s) to check on:</td>
                <td> <%=(string)Session["Step04OtherField"] %></td>
            </row>
        </table>
```