# Display Code From A Database with C#

Tags: c#

I have a database with almost 2000 code examples that I've collected over the last 10 years that I want to be able to access with a textarea field so I can copy and/or update easily. I'm trying to migrate from PHP to C# on a new domain, but I'm having problems getting it to display correctly.

This is how it looks currently: http://nunyabiz.freeiz.com/csharp/index.html

This is how it's supposed to look: http://nunyabiz.freeiz.com/csharp/index2.html

This is the code that I'm using to display it:
`Code.Text = rs["Code"].ToString().Replace("\r\n", "\n");`

The "\r\n" characters aren't getting recognized, so I'm guessing that I have to convert,  encode or decode it, but I haven't had any luck trying to find something that will work.  online.

Comment: duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3944410/textbox-with-new-line

Comment: Could it be that `rs["Code"]` contains the *literal* escape values seen? (That is a two-char sequence of \,r or \,n). Remember that "\r" and "\n" only work in *string literals*: not if the escapes are stored as such in the DB. (What is the result of a simple select from the DB CLI?)

Comment: It's quite possible that they could be the literal escape values. How would I convert them back to string literals?

Answer (score 0):

you can try `Environment.NewLine` for Linebreaks  [Environment.Newline](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.newline.aspx)

```
strYourCode = string.Format("Name: {0}  LineBreak {1}", yournameVariable, Environment.NewLine);
```

Comment: I'm not completely sure how to implement that with my code. I just tried: [code] Code.Text = rs["Code"].ToString().Replace("\r\n", Environment.NewLine);[/code] without any success...

Answer (score 0):

Try to figure out WHAT line breaks you have in your code samples - there are many variants including html tag br, and then change it to what you need (i think it is Environment.Newline)

And check that your Code control is Multiline

Comment: the majority of them are "\r\n" but the replace function doesn't seem to be catching them

Comment: it is Multiline, btw: <asp:TextBox id="Code" runat="server" Rows="35" TextMode="MultiLine" Width="100%"></asp:TextBox>

Comment: I just tested the following and it works perfectly: 

String CodeToTest = "<style>\r\n#explanation {\r\n display: none;\r\n}\r\n</style>\r\n";
Code.Text = CodeToTest.Replace(Environment.NewLine, "\n");

However, it doesn't work when I try to replace it in the code that's stored in the database. It seems to not recognize "\r\n" as newline characters. Any idea how I can get it to recognize them appropriately?

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try `.Replace("\r", "").Replace("\n", "<br/>");`